# Angular Service Worker - Cryptography SHA1

Tags: angular, hash, cryptography, service-worker

My project was scanned by **CheckMarx** and I got:

> "Client Weak Cryptographic Hash" : The application employs weak
> hashing in **sha1**

for the angular service worker.
It found it on 3 different js files:

```
ngsw-worker.js: return sha1(JSON.stringify(manifest));
safety-worker.js: return sha1(JSON.stringify(manifest));
worker-basic.min.js: return sha1(JSON.stringify(manifest));
```

Is there a way\version where the service worker uses a stronger hashing or a way to configure it?
Copilot claims there is an **"integrity"** property I can use in the assetsGroups of the ngsw-config.json, but it is not recognized.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is not "is SHA-1" used but "for what purpose is SHA-1 used".  If the generated SHA-1 digest is not used for cryptography or other security relevant actions then you don't have to care about.